# Updating an MS Bookings appointments removes Teams meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, outlook-calendar, microsoft-graph-booking

We are using the Graph API (both via REST API and the SDK) to manage appointments in an MS Bookings calendar. When creating an appointment using a [POST request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-post-appointments?view=graph-rest-1.0) and specifying [`isLocationOnline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/bookingappointment?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) to "true", the appointment in the calendar gets successfully created with an embedded Teams meeting link. We are also defining some metadata within the `serviceNotes` of the appointment.

Now, we are trying to perform an update operation using a [PATCH request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingappointment-update?view=graph-rest-1.0), and we've observed that in the below scenarios the Teams meeting is removed after performing the update:

- Request body contains only `serviceNotes`

```bash
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses/{Business}/appointments/{AppointmentID}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {BearerToken}' \
--data-raw '{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingAppointment",
    "serviceNotes": "Update notes"
}'
```

- Request body contains only `serviceNotes` and `isLocationOnline`

```bash
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses/{Business}/appointments/{AppointmentID}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {BearerToken}' \
--data-raw '{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingAppointment",
    "isLocationOnline": true,
    "serviceNotes": "Update notes"
}'
```

- Request body contains only `startDateTime`, `endDateTime` and `serviceNotes`

```bash
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses/{Business}/appointments/{AppointmentID}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {BearerToken}' \
--data-raw '{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingAppointment",
    "startDateTime": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.dateTimeTimeZone",
        "dateTime": "2023-06-02T10:30:00.0000000+00:00",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "endDateTime": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.dateTimeTimeZone",
        "dateTime": "2023-06-02T11:30:00.0000000+00:00",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "serviceNotes": "Update notes"
}'
```

In all the above cases, the Teams meeting is lost following the update, and it seems it happens when we touch the `serviceNotes`. The below resources mention similar issues with the Graph's Calendars API where on updating the event, the Teams meeting no longer exists.

- [Microsoft team link is not appearing for alternate update calendar events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65320427)
- [Updating event via MS Graph API removing Join Button in the event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65202246)

The recommended workaround is to perform an update on the Calendar event without updating the body, however, to do so would mean that the ["Calendars.ReadWrite" permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) would be required first to be granted, and this permission exposes all the calendars in the organisation ([permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#calendars-permissions)).

A dirty workaround we were thinking of is to perform a cancel operation before re-creating the appointment. Is there a cleaner alternative to this issue which sits solely within the realm of MS Bookings?

Comment: For Microsoft Booking related issue, kindly request you to raise here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-bookings/bd-p/MicrosoftBookings

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I've raised this in the [forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1293570/updating-service-notes-loses-teams-meeting) but got no reply just yet. Although not an apt solution, we ended up cancelling and re-creating an appointment as a workaround.